# Find an infinite orthonormal set

Tags: functional-analysis

Find an infinite orthonormal set in the Hilbert space H=the collection of all absolutely continuous functions $f:[0,1]\to F$ such that f(0)=0 and $f^{'}\in L^2(0,1)$, by the inner product $(f,g)=\int_0^1 f'(t)\bar{g'(t)} dt$

Answer (score 1):

This question is posed in a bit of a strange way since, rather than work with the absolutely continuous functions $f \in H$, you can just work with their derivatives $f' \in L^1(0,1) \cap L^2(0,1)$.  That is, rather than consider $H$ as it is definied, why not just consider $K = L^2(0,1) \cap L^1(0,1)$? This way, the inner product on $K$ is just the one it inherits as a subapce of $L^2(0,1)$.

Now, it is not difficult to exhibit an infinite orthonormal set in $K$, just take scalar multiples of characteristic functions of disjoint intervals (which will need to get shorter in order to fit infinitely many of them into $(0,1)$).

Something to think about, however. Is $K$ actually closed in $L^2(0,1)$ so that it is, itself, a Hilbert space?

Comment: @ Mike, I have to find continuous functions ;but characteristic functions are not cont on [0,1]. Am I right?

Comment: My point is that the derivatives of the absolutely continuous functions are precisely the $L^1$ functions, and these do not need to be continuous.

Comment: But for these characteristic functions do not exit cont functions where these characteristic functions are their derivatives.

Comment: Example: $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} x & \text{ when } 0 < x \leq 1/2 \\ 1/2 & \text{ when } 1/2 \leq x < 1 \\ \end{cases}.$$ Then, the derivative $f'$ equals $1$ on $(0,1/2)$ and $0$ on $(1/2,1)$. Even though $f$ is not differentiable at $1/2$, we still get an element of $L^1(0,1)$ from $f'$ since values of $f'$ only matter up to changes on a null set.

Comment: @ Mike, Tanks for your attention